# Как получить информацию из строки json, которая указана в Javascript коде внутри html страницы, используя python3.x?

Tags: html, python, json, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть один код, который парсит html с помощью requests.get.

Далее из полученного html мне необходимо взять json строку ...

```
<script>
    try{
        try{
            var card = JSON.parse('{"CardPAN":"1234567890123456789","EndDate":"01.01.2016","TicketTypeDesc":"00.04 CardName","CityName":"City","CardSum":99,"Time":"01.09.2016 11:11:01"}');
        }
 ...
```

из которой мне необходим параметр CardSum.

Пытался с помощью beautifulsoup что-то вроде `soup.find_all('try'))` и `soup.find_all('var'))` и `soup.find('var', 'CardSum')` и так далее - везде выходило пустое значение.

Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How to extract a JSON object that was defined in a HTML page javascript block using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13323976/4279)

Comment: примеры использования `slimit`, `pyjsparser` javascript парсеров:  [Как можно отсортировать js-файл по населению в Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/783572/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests.get()` вызов не распознаёт html, он просто загружает указанную страницу. Чтобы распознать html, нужен html-парсер. Чтобы распознать javascript, нужен javascript парсер. Чтобы распознать json, нужен json парсер.

Простейший (и самый хрупкий вариант) это просто использовать регулярное выражение, чтобы получить необходимую информацию:

```
card_sum = int(re.search(r'"CardSum"\s*:\s*(\d+)', html).group(1))
```

Можно [комбинировать применение парсеров с регулярными выражениями, чтобы повысить устойчивость и общность кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13325474/4279).

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто. JSON надо преобразовать в объект, и оттуда взять нужное.

```
inputString = '{YOUR_JSON_STRING}'
resultData = json.loads(resultString)
```

И в `resultData['CardSum']` ваши данные.

Comment: Спасибо. Это понятно. Но вот как забрать сам json из html кода страницы - пока для меня загадка.

Comment: @S.Stuart скачиваете страницу, обрабатываете регэкспами :) Вообще, можно подумать в сторону `slimit`, советовали [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25112096/5980797).

Comment: @approximatenumber: [воспользовался вашей рекомендацией](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13325474/4279): `slimit` работает, но документация и удобство использования оставляют желать лучшего. Хотя [код](https://github.com/rspivak/slimit) достаточно прост, поэтому имея конкретную задачу (что хочется из javascipt изъять), можно найти как `slimit` может помочь.