# Python json запись в csv: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: javascript, python, регулярные-выражения, json, парсер

Добрый день Есть json

```js
var model = {"ALLSKUS":["84664020","07961015","84664113","84664116"],"NBR":"137127","PRICERANGE":"$186.99 - $189.99","GENDER_AGE":"Men's","PRICEADJUSTDATE":"","AVAILABLE_SIZES":[" 07.5"," 08.0"," 08.5"," 09.0"," 09.5"," 10.0"," 10.5"," 11.0"," 11.5"," 12.0"," 12.5"," 13.0","14.0","15.0"],"DISCOUNT_PERCENT":"15","isFieldTestable":false,"SORT":"152","HASCUSTOMPRODUCTTEMPLATE":false,"PR_LIST":"224.99","SPORTS":[{"ID":"3","NM":"Basketball"},{"ID":"39","NM":"Casual"}],"SIZECHART_CD":"S0584","HASSIZES":true,"PR_SALE":"189.99","LOCALIZATION":{},"MODELTEMPLATE":{"ISMODELTEMPLATEACTIVE":"N","MODELTEMPLATE_IMAGE":""},"ISCUSTOMPRODUCT":false,"INTRODUCTIONDATE":"","SKU":"84664020","ISINTANGIBLE":false,"PROD_TP":"Shoes","CUSTPROD_CD":"","NM":"Jordan Retro 6 - Men's","REVIEWS":
```

1. я ищу это

   ```
   "AVAILABLE_SIZES":[" 07.5"," 08.0"," 08.5"," 09.0"," 09.5"," 10.0"," 10.5"," 11.0"," 11.5"," 12.0"," 12.5"," 13.0"," 14.0"," 15.0"]
   ```

потом я убираю все лишнее

2. На выходе должно быть таблица.csv

   ```
   |размер|размер|размер|размер|размер|размер|размер|размер|размер|размер|
   |07.0|07.5|08.0|10.0|10.5|11.5|12.0"|13.0|14.0|15|
   ```
3. Пишу это в csv

Данные я ищу через регулярные выражения:

```py
ad = requests.get('http://www.footlocker.com/product/model:132512/sku:A1781919/timberland-roll-top-mens/tan/tan/').text #сылка для примера

 bb = re.findall(r'"AVAILABLE_SIZES":(.*)"DISCOUNT_PERCENT"', ad)

out: ['[" 07.0"," 07.5"," 08.0"," 10.0"," 10.5"," 11.5"," 12.0"," 13.0"," 14.0"," 15.0"],']
```

Дальше я их убираю лишнее данные

как теперь убрать лишнее?
На replace ругается.
На выходе ошибка, пробела в некорректном выводе json?

```py
 out:


bb = re.findall(r'"AVAILABLE_SIZES":(.*)],"DISCOUNT_PERCENT"', ad).str(var).replace('[', ' ')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'
```

### update

```py
bb_strings = re.findall(r'var model = ({.*})', ad)
    bp = {}
    if bb_strings:
    bp = json.loads(bb_strings[0])

out: {'ALLSKUS': ['A1781919', '6635A001', '6634A'], 'NBR': '132512', 'PRICERANGE': '$99.99 - $125.99', 'GENDER_AGE': "Men's", 'PRICEADJUSTDATE': '', 'AVAILABLE_SIZES': [' 07.0', ' 07.5', ' 08.0', ' 10.0', ' 10.5', ' 11.5', ' 12.0', ' 13.0', ' 14.0', ' 15.0'], 'DISCOUNT_PERCENT': '10', 'isFieldTestable': False, 'SORT': '1036', 'HASCUSTOMPRODUCTTEMPLATE': False, 'PR_LIST': '139.99', 'SPORTS': [{'ID': '31', 'NM': 'Snow'}, {'ID': '39', 'NM': 'Casual'}], 'SIZECHART_CD': 'S0629', 'HASSIZES': True, 'PR_SALE': '125.99', 'LOCALIZATION': {}, 'MODELTEMPLATE': {'ISMODELTEMPLATEACTIVE': 'N', 'MODELTEMPLATE_IMAGE': ''}, 'ISCUSTOMPRODUCT': False, 'INTRODUCTIONDATE': '', 'SKU': '6635A001', 'ISINTANGIBLE': False, 'PROD_TP': 'Shoes', 'CUSTPROD_CD': '', 'NM': "Timberland Roll-Top - Men's", 'REVIEWS': {'HASREVIEWS': True, 'TOTALREVIEWCOUNT': '17', 'WEIGHTEDAVERAGERATING': '4.82', 'WEIGHTEDAVERAGERECOMMENDED': '16'}, 'BRAND': 'Timberland', 'INET_COPY': 'A style unlike any other. The Timberland Roll Top Boot rolls down for a little built-in air conditioning and a whole lotta style. Premium, full-grain leather upper provides comfort, durability and abrasion resistance. Direct-attach seam construction promises lasting durability. Padded collar provides a comfortable fit around the ankle and keeps out debris. Rubber lug sole for traction and durability. Embossed Timberland tree logo on the side.'}

for bl in bp['AVAILABLE_SIZES']:
    footlocker.append(('размер', bl))
```

все норм работает, как теперь сделать что в csv писались все данные а не первые значения?

теперь нужно достать данные которые нужны

Comment: Помимо того, что вы плохо пишите по-русски, неплохо было бы поправить вопрос, чтобы он был читаемым хотя бы технически (отступы, выделения и т.п.).

Comment: По предоставленной вами ссылке нет никакого JSON - там обычная текстовая страница. Удаляйте/извлекайте данные только после того, как JSON будет десериализирован, то есть преобразован из текста в древовидный объект - не нужно работать с JSON, как с текстом, тем более таким топорным как у вас (регулярки) методом. Конкретно в вашем случае лишняя запятая - самый последний символ в вашем JSON массиве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall()` возвращает cписок (тип `list`). У списка нет метода `str()`. Помимо общих [методов для (изменяемых) последовательностей](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range), list предоставляет только [`sort()` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists).

Интерактивно, в REPL (ptpython, ipython) поиграйтесь: посмотрите, что `re.findall()` возвращает, какие методы у списка автодополнение показывает. Полный список методов можно увидеть в выводе `help(list)`.

См. [Как получить информацию из строки json, которая указана в Javascript коде внутри html страницы, используя python3.x?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501630/23044)

Comment: обновил теперь json на выходе, осталось убрать лишнее

Comment: @fermeg если у вас возникла новая проблема, то следует новый вопрос задавать, а не старый исправлять,