# Как, используя Beautuful Soup, искать по ключевому слову если это слово находится в теге script?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Всем привет! Вопрос: делаю поиск по странице через Beautuful Soup, теги прекрасно находятся через find_all или find, а как написать команду для поиска просто ключевого слова, даже если это слово находится в теге script? Допустим если нашел на странице mysite.com слово company (в тексте страницы это выглядит так: company = gazprom) в теге script, выводить значение gazprom? В документации не нашел
пример html:

```
> <script type="text/javascript">params={"ends": null, "ends2":
> {"secret": "THSGDJIqnR9Sc1KyZF4dArgTIiIgPIbu", "view": null},
> "country": "RU", "language": "ru", "data": "data", "company" :
> "gazprom", "data2" : "data2" ...
```

мне нужно получить одно слово со страницы: gazprom

Comment: @maxu <script type="text/javascript">params={"ends": null, "ends2": {"secret": "THSGDJIqnR9Sc1KyZF4dArgTIiIgPIbu", "view": null}, "country": "RU", "language": "ru", "data": ... и так далее

Comment: @maxu обновил вопрос, через find получается вывести только все содержимое script, что не подходит, нужно только одно слово

Comment: так вопрос выглядит значительно лучше...

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как получить информацию из строки json, которая указана в Javascript коде внутри html страницы, используя python3.x?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501556/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                params={
                        "ends": null,
                        "ends2": {"secret": "THSGDJIqnR9Sc1KyZF4dArgTIiIgPIbu", "view": null},
                        "country": "RU",
                        "language": "ru",
                        "data": "data",
                        "company":      "gazprom",
                        "data2": "data2"
                }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
script = soup.find('script')
companies = re.findall(r'[\'\"]company[\'\"]\s*\:\s*[\'\"]([^\'\"]*)[\'\"]',
                       script.text, flags=re.I)
```

Результат:

```
In [123]: companies
Out[123]: ['gazprom']
```

Answer (score 1):

Помимо регулярных выражений, чтобы искать значения внутри JavaScript кода, можно использовать JavaScript парсер. BeautifulSoup не является javascript парсером — эта библиотека распознаёт html (содержимое `<script>` элемента непрозрачно).

Используя JavaScript парсер, предоставляемый [`slimit` модулем](http://slimit.readthedocs.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Find `params.company` in javascript."""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4
from slimit import ast  # $ pip install slimit
from slimit.parser import Parser as JavascriptParser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

def find_by_name(tree, name):
    return next(node.right for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
                if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and node.left.value == name)


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tree = JavascriptParser().parse(soup.script.string)
params = find_by_name(tree, 'params')
company = find_by_name(params, '"company"')
print(company.value) # -> "gazprom"
```

`BeautifulSoup` используется, чтобы содержимое `<script>` элемента как текст достать,
который затем передаётся в Javascipt парсер, который [AST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) создаёт,
из которого при обходе узел, содержащий `params` находится,
из которого значение, соответствующее `"company"` изымается.