# Как можно отсортировать js-файл по населению в Питоне

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, сортировка

Помогите с этим заданием. Есть json файл с данными типа

```
const data = [
    {
        ID: 'AD',
        country: 'Andorra',
        population: 84000
    },
    {
        ID: 'AE',
        country: 'United Arab Emirates',
        population: 4975593
    },
```

и тд. 
Приведите пример как можно отсортировать файл по населению.
Вывод любой подойдет.
https://gist.github.com/nexusloh/7f67abb4f9313f20b5cf9f57cf58e8c1
файлик полный

Comment: К слову, я находил примеры с сортировкой подобных данных но я не могу понять как мне взять эти файлы не переписывая все в питон и обрабатывая там

Comment: Это точно данные из json файла?

Comment: @Денис да, могу кинуть полный файлик

Comment: @Денис Заминочка вышла, это js файл
https://gist.github.com/nexusloh/7f67abb4f9313f20b5cf9f57cf58e8c1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала необходимо преобразовать данные из файла в массив словарей:

```
import re

text = open("data.txt", "r").read()

text = re.sub("(const data = |;)", "", text)             # удаляем "const data = " и ";"
text = re.sub(r'(?P<name>\w*):', "'\g<name>':", text)    # ключам словарей добавляем одинарные кавычки

data = eval(text)    # выполняем текст как код python
```

После этого `data` можно отсортировать по полю `population` следующим образом:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data.sort(key=itemgetter('population'))
print(data)
```

Если необходима сортировка по убыванию, то в метод `sort` надо передать дополнительно `reverse=True`

Comment: Окей, но как пайтон поймет откуда брать данные. Все это в отделом файле.

Comment: прикрепите файл к вопросу

Comment: изменил ответ, должно сработать.

Comment: спасибо, все работает. мб еще подскажите как выводить данные с новой строки, а то все в одну строку в консоль выводит

Comment: Главное чтобы в production eval не тащили...

Comment: @Qwertiy можно на `ast.literal_eval()` попробовать заменить или лучше в настоящий json привести и на json.loads() заменить. Или вообще вместо своих регулярных выражений использовать настоящий javascript парсер как показано в моём ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Для более устойчивого к небольшим изменениям ввода разбора javascript кода, можно использовать javascript парсер, вместо ad hoc регулярных выражений:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
import pyjsparser  # $ pip install pyjsparser


def find_by_name(obj, name):
    return next(prop['value']['value'] for prop in obj['properties']
                if prop['key']['name'] == name)


program = pyjsparser.parse(Path('qqq.js').read_text())
arr = program['body'][0]['declarations'][0]['init']['elements']
arr.sort(key=lambda obj: find_by_name(obj, 'population'),
         reverse=True)
pprint(arr)
```

Вывод здесь отсортированный по убыванию значения population [AST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) массива, представленного как список словарей в Питоне:

```py
[
  {
    "properties": [
      {
        "computed": false,
        "key": {
          "name": "ID",
          "type": "Identifier"
        },
        "kind": "init",
        "method": false,
        "shorthand": false,
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
          "raw": null,
          "type": "Literal",
          "value": "CN"
        }
      },
      {
        "computed": false,
        "key": {
          "name": "country",
          "type": "Identifier"
        },
        "kind": "init",
        "method": false,
        "shorthand": false,
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
          "raw": null,
          "type": "Literal",
          "value": "China"
        }
      },
      {
        "computed": false,
        "key": {
          "name": "population",
          "type": "Identifier"
        },
        "kind": "init",
        "method": false,
        "shorthand": false,
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
          "raw": null,
          "type": "Literal",
          "value": 1330044000.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "ObjectExpression"
  },
  {
    "properties": [
      {
        "computed": false,
        "key": {
          "name": "ID",
          "type": "Identifier"
        },
        "kind": "init",
        "method": false,
        "shorthand": false,
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
          "raw": null,
          "type": "Literal",
          "value": "IN"
        }
      },
      {
        "computed": false,
        "key": {
          "name": "country",
          "type": "Identifier"
        },
        "kind": "init",
        "method": false,
        "shorthand": false,
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
          "raw": null,
          "type": "Literal",
          "value": "India"
        }
      },
      {
        "computed": false,
        "key": {
          "name": "population",
          "type": "Identifier"
        },
        "kind": "init",
        "method": false,
        "shorthand": false,
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
          "raw": null,
          "type": "Literal",
          "value": 1173108018.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "ObjectExpression"
  },
  ...
]
```

Легко только желаемые значения показывать:

```py
for node in arr:
    print(*[prop['value']['value'] for prop in node['properties']])
```

Результат:

```py
CN China 1330044000.0
IN India 1173108018.0
US United States 310232863.0
```

---

Вот пример, который выводит отсортированный результат как javascript код:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
# $ pip install git+https://github.com/fflexo/slimit.git@const#egg=slimit
from slimit.parser import Parser as JavascriptParser


def find_by_name(obj, name):
    return next(prop.right.value for prop in obj.properties
                if prop.left.value == name)


tree = JavascriptParser().parse(Path('qqq.js').read_text())
# const statement -> const decl -> array
arr = tree.children()[0].children()[0].children()[1]  # const data = [
arr.items.sort(key=lambda obj: int(find_by_name(obj, 'population')),
               reverse=True)
print(tree.to_ecma())
```

Результат:

```js
const data = [{
  ID: 'CN',
  country: 'China',
  population: 1330044000
},{
  ID: 'IN',
  country: 'India',
  population: 1173108018
}, 
...
];
```