# Как опарсить url с лишними '\' из текста регулярными выражениями в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Как отпарсить из текста ссылку такого вида:

```
https:\/\/www.aptekazhivika.ru\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a05e171a5a1348658a0feb46a8ffae67\/3\/4\/34181-a-a-5-b-aa5b31670468eedfc63a230ea9af2b7a72ed0567_34181_1.jpg
```

Результат должен содержать список или массив ссылок и можно привести их к нормальному виду (https//www.domain.ru/).
UPD:

Ссылки берутся отсюда:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": {"fullscreenzoom":"20","top":"","left":"","width":"","height":"","eventType":"hover","enabled":"false"},
                "data": [{"thumb":"https:\/\/www.aptekazhivika.ru\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a05e171a5a1348658a0feb46a8ffae67\/3\/4\/34181-4-5-d-2-45d21bb09daf80bd827d57a372668841eeff2424_34181.jpg","img":"https:\/\/www.aptekazhivika.ru\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/c687aa7517cf01e65c009f6943c2b1e9\/3\/4\/34181-4-5-d-2-45d21bb09daf80bd827d57a372668841eeff2424_34181.jpg","full":"https:\/\/www.aptekazhivika.ru\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/926507dc7f93631a094422215b778fe0\/3\/4\/34181-4-5-d-2-45d21bb09daf80bd827d57a372668841eeff2424_34181.jpg","caption":"","position":"0","isMain":true},{"thumb":"https:\/\/www.aptekazhivika.ru\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a05e171a5a1348658a0feb46a8ffae67\/3\/4\/34181-a-a-5-b-aa5b31670468eedfc63a230ea9af2b7a72ed0567_34181_1.jpg","img":"https:\/\/www.aptekazhivika.ru\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/c687aa7517cf01e65c009f6943c2b1e9\/3\/4\/34181-a-a-5-b-aa5b31670468eedfc63a230ea9af2b7a72ed0567_34181_1.jpg","full":"https:\/\/www.aptekazhivika.ru\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/926507dc7f93631a094422215b778fe0\/3\/4\/34181-a-a-5-b-aa5b31670468eedfc63a230ea9af2b7a72ed0567_34181_1.jpg","caption":"","position":"0","isMain":false}],
                "options": {
                    "nav": "thumbs",
                                            "loop": true,
                                                                "keyboard": true,
                                                                "arrows": false,
                                                                "allowfullscreen": true,
                                                                "showCaption": false,
                                        "width": "370",
                    "thumbwidth": "60",
                                            "thumbheight": 60,
                                                                "height": 370,
                                                                "transitionduration": 500,
                                        "transition": "slide",
                                            "navarrows": true,
                                        "navtype": "slides",
                    "navdir": "horizontal"
                },
                "fullscreen": {
                    "nav": "thumbs",
                                            "loop": true,
                                        "navdir": "horizontal",
                                        "navtype": "slides",
                                            "arrows": false,
                                                                "showCaption": false,
                                                                "transitionduration": 500,
                                        "transition": "dissolve"
                },
                "breakpoints": {"mobile":{"conditions":{"max-width":"767px"},"options":{"options":{"nav":"dots","allowfullscreen":false}}}}            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Самый правильный ответ зависит от того, как и откуда вы эту ссылку вообще получили

Comment: @andreymal, я добавил UPD

Comment: А, ну так JSON-объект лучше JSON-парсером и парсить без всяких регулярок

Comment: @andreymal, у меня EOL получилось.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как получить информацию из строки json, которая указана в Javascript коде внутри html страницы, используя python3.x?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501556/23044)

Answer (score 0):

На случай если нужна всё же регулярка вот, может пригодится

```
http(s)?:\\/\\\/([a-zA-Z\d._-]+(\\\/)?)+
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/259545)

Comment: @norbornen эмм, странно. Может я сформировал предложение не как ответ. Но решением поставленной задачи это является как является и "ответом" на "вопрос" задачу. Я не прав?