# Получить данные из js. Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, парсер

```
<script>
window.statistic_popup_main.app
.setParams({'1':'2'})
.setAdditionalParams({'3':'4'})
</script>
```

и тд
подскажите, пожалуйста как получить данные из этих переменных (словари)?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как получить информацию из строки json, которая указана в Javascript коде внутри html страницы, используя python3.x?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501556/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Парсинг регуляркой и сериализация через json:

```py
import json
import re

text = """\
<script>
window.statistic_popup_main.app
.setParams({'1':'2'})
.setAdditionalParams({'3':'4'})
</script>
"""

for match in re.findall(r'\(({.+})\)', text):
    # Иначе будет ошибка: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes ...
    match = match.replace("'", '"')

    data = json.loads(match)
    print(data)
```

Или парсить можно через `ast`:

```py
import ast
import re


for match in re.findall(r'\(({.+})\)', text):
    data = ast.literal_eval(match)
    print(data)
```

Консоль:

```
{'1': '2'}
{'3': '4'}
```

Comment: Вот это да! А я даже не понял, о чем вопрос (.

Comment: @Igor, я и сейчас не уверен, что угадал. Может быть там и не парсить нужно. Посмотрим на реакцию автора :)

Comment: @gil9red Не поверите, я Вам в вк собирался написать (нашел похожую статью 17 года), но потом передумал!!!))) А таким способом к определенной переменной обращаться можно?

Comment: @АлексейТихонов Можно. Сохраните `data` в список, например (`items.append(data)`). И после цикла вызывайте: `items[0]['1']` `items[1]['3']`

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлексейТихонов, если мой ответ вас устроил, то [отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)